# Problems with Install to Gazebo 3

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Everyone!!

I have problems when try to install Gazebo3 for Ubuntu 12.04

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/3.0/install

I used:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gazebo3
```

Error:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
gazebo3 ya está en su versión más reciente.
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
gazebo3 : Depende: libsdformat2 pero no va a instalarse
gazebo3-plugin-base : Depende: libsdformat2 pero no va a instalarse
libgazebo-dev : Depende: libprotoc-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libprotobuf-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libogre-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libtar-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libcegui-mk2-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libgts-dev pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libsdformat2-dev pero no va a instalarse
 libgazebo3 : Depende: libcegui-mk2-0.7.5 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libogre-1.7.4 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libplayercommon3.0 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libplayercore3.0 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libsdformat2 pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libtar0 pero no va a instalarse
 libplayerc++3.0 : Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 pero no va a instalarse
 libplayerc3.0 : Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 pero no va a instalarse
 libplayercommon3.0-dev : Depende: libplayercommon3.0 (= 3.0.2+dfsg-3ubuntu2) pero no va a instalarse
 libplayercore3.0-dev : Depende: libplayercore3.0 (= 3.0.2+dfsg-3ubuntu2) pero no va a instalarse
 libplayerdrivers3.0 : Depende: libplayercommon3.0 pero no va a instalarse
                   Depende: libplayercore3.0 pero no va a instalarse
                   Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 pero no va a instalarse
 libplayerinterface3.0-dev : Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 (= 3.0.2+dfsg-3ubuntu2) pero no va a instalarse
 libplayertcp3.0 : Depende: libplayercommon3.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: libplayercore3.0 pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: libplayerinterface3.0 pero no va a instalarse
 libplayerwkb3.0 : Depende: libplayercommon3.0 pero no va a instalarse
 ros-hydro-class-loader : Depende: libpocofoundation9 pero no va a instalarse
                      Depende: libpoco-dev pero no va a instalarse
 ros-hydro-gazebo3-plugins : Depende: libogre-1.7.4 pero no va a instalarse
                         Depende: libsdformat2 pero no va a instalarse
 ros-hydro-gazebo3-ros : Depende: libsdformat2 pero no va a instalarse
 ros-hydro-rosgraph : Depende: python-netifaces pero no va a instalarse
 ros-hydro-roslisp : Depende: sbcl pero no va a instalarse
 E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

And when try to use in the Terminal $ gazebo, get this error:

```
gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libsdformat.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A lot of thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6707/problems-with-install-to-gazebo-3/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like you are missing an installation from packages and a try to compile gazebo from scratch. If this is your case, please be sure to clean up first all gazebo stuff from your system (find /usr -name gazebo could help to detect what needs to be cleaned up).

Once this is done, proceed with a simple:

```
apt-get install -f
```

That was in your log and probably the package manager was not in a good state. And after fixing the errors, try again the installation.

I was able to launch the apt-get install gazebo3 into a precise system without any problem so I'm assuming that the problem could be in your system.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-28**:
Great!
Used:

```
apt-get -f install
```

And problem solved,

A lot of thanks!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-07-29**:
Perfect! could you please mark my answer as valid by clicking on the check signal?